# good player to use for audio books

Tags: windows-media-player, audiobook

i just find that is useful to listen audio books, but when it is about tacking notices, the play/pause, adding bookmarks is impossible with the regular players(windows media player, vlc, bsplayer, winamp). Do you know a better alternative to that?

Answer (score 2):

I use Angle's Vox http://www.superutils.com/tag/angels-vox/ It's specifically designed for audio books, unfortunately, it's not free :(